# Replace a character which is in braces and not enclosed in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace `=` with `:` where it is in a braces and is not inside a single or double quote (converting c# constructor to javascript}:

```
{name = 'John', something = "a=1", another = 'b=1'}
```

the result would be:

```
{name : 'John', something = "a=1", another = 'b=1'}
```

I have tried a lot and this is the final thing that I came up with but does exactly opposite of what I want (changes only those which are in quotes)

```
 ss = ss.replace(/({[^}]+([^'"]))(=)((?:[^'"])(?:[^}]+)})/g, '$1:$4');
```

and this is the result:

> {name = 'John', something = "a=1", another = 'b:1'}

and this

```
/({[^}]+([^'"]))(=)((?:\2)(?:[^}]+)})/g
```

does not match at all

Comment: *"...and not enclosed in quotes"* You can't do it reliably *just* a regular expression in JavaScript, it doesn't have the necessary features to correctly handle delimiter matching and escaping (which are outside the realm of "regex" per se, but some engines have features that do it). You'll have to parse.

Comment: What do those attempts result in? Could you add that to your answer, because I'm having trouble visualizing what you mean

Comment: @cdomination I'm trying to parse a c# class constructor in javascript. so `{ name = value}` should become `{ name : value}` but I'm trying to avoid changing `=` which might exist in the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this,

```js
var s = "{name = 'John', something = \"a=1\", another = 'b=1'}";

console.log(s.replace(/=(?=\s*(['"])((?!\1).)*\1)/g, ':'))
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lotttt

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani but it has some edgecases.. If your format is like above then you're free to use this regex..